# Expose a docker port on Mac Osx to other computer

Tags: macos, docker

I would like to open a docker port running on a mac Osx to other computer on the same network.

I've found some work around but only with boot2docker not toolbox.

And not the simple -p or -P. I would like to access to the docker port running on a MacOsx from an other computer on the same network.

Regards and thanks

Comment: So share us what you did in boot2docker?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Port forwarding should work exactly the same way as with boot2docker.

```
VBoxManage controlvm "<name_of_your_vm>" natpf1 "tcp-port8000,tcp,,8000,,8000";
```

Then you should be able to access port 8000 under

```
localhost:8000
```

and from different computer in the same network

```
<ip_of_you_machine>:8000
```

For more information check this boot2doicker github page [Workarounds](https://github.com/boot2docker/boot2docker/blob/master/doc/WORKAROUNDS.md)